# Grails JAX-RS getting data from JSON

Tags: grails, jax-rs

i'm using the Grails JAX-RS plugin in one of my project for a REST server - the work between the client and the server is by JSON.
i'm having problems posting the data from the server. the domain object is bind but not all the field is filled - i think the problem is with the nested object.